# LaTeX hanging paragraphs

Tags: latex, indentation

I'd like to set up my paragraphs to hang **only** on the second line. The [hanging environment](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hanging/hanging.pdf) will hang *after* a particular line, but not on a specific line.

To piggyback off of another question [LaTeX: indent from second line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254054/latex-indent-from-second-line), I want it to produce something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Proin eu tempor velit. Fusce accumsan ultrices fringilla. Praesent 
sed odio mi. Mauris non ligula turpis. Duis posuere lacus nec diam 
interdum dictum suscipit magna molestie. Vestibulum nibh dolor, 
interdum eget rhoncus ut, sodales eget justo. Morbi blandit lorem 
sit amet nulla egestas aliquam. Nunc pharetra est at nibh ullamcorper 
in commodo erat dignissim. Cras et suscipit enim. 

Nunc adipiscing ligula at ligula egestas id ullamcorper felis luctus. 
    Aliquam tincidunt turpis sed eros pellentesque iaculis. Nulla 
imperdiet cursus enim condimentum congue.
```

It would also be nice if this could be a set document wide instead of just an environment, but not necessary.

EDIT: Here is my best example of what each paragraph looks like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eu tempor velit. Fusce accumsan ultrices fringilla. Praesent sed odio mi. Mauris non ligula turpis. Duis posuere lacus nec diam interdum dictum suscipit magna molestie. Vestibulum nibh dolor, interdum eget rhoncus ut, sodales eget justo. Morbi blandit lorem sit amet nulla egestas aliquam. Nunc pharetra est at nibh ullamcorper in commodo erat dignissim. Cras et suscipit enim.\\

Nunc adipiscing ligula at ligula egestas id ullamcorper felis luctus. Aliquam tincidunt turpis sed eros pellentesque iaculis. Nulla imperdiet cursus enim condimentum congue.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: What comes *before* your first line? A section? Alternatively, what makes up the "division" (a blank line in your post) between the "paragraphs" you show?

Comment: This is the start of a new paragraph, so it's preceded either by a `\\ ` or `\par `.

Comment: So how do you then distinguish between the first and the second paragraph? You show two such instances in your example. You should really provide some code that replicates what you want. It may just make things clear.

Comment: When looking for an example I found out that this is called a "drop word". This is common in Hebrew text. [This](https://indesignsecrets.com/creating-dropwords-indesign.php) is some product that does it for you. Paragraphs are also distinguished by a bolded first (few) word(s), but it's not necessary.

Comment: You're still not helping... Can you provide us with your expected input through *code*?

Comment: see the edit to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

You can update `\everypar` to insert a specific `\parshape`. This should re-organize the flow to match your requirement:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum}

\newlength{\saveparindent}\setlength{\saveparindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\updateeverypar}{%
  \parshape 3
    0pt \linewidth
    \saveparindent \dimexpr\linewidth-\saveparindent\relax
    0pt \linewidth}


\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@xsect}{\ignorespaces}{\ignorespaces\everypar{\updateeverypar}}{}{}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\everypar{\updateeverypar}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-3]

\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

Note though that `\everypar` may be updated unexpectedly within standard document elements. See, for example, the spacing above **1 Introduction** compared to that of **2 Conclusion**. Depending on your application or usage, this might be a problem or not, and may require adjustments.

Comment: This is excellent! It works perfectly with the file I've been working on. Another file (which is a huge mess) I get an undefined control sequence at `\chapter ` and `\tableofcontents `. I comment out the line to see if it will chug out the rest, but it doesn't. The second file is a `[report] ` instead of an `[article] `

Comment: Nevermind. I got it working on all documents. Thanks again!